# EC-2 CentOs: User is not in the sudoers file

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have an EC-2 instance where i need to edit a file through SSH. I keep getting "{user} is no in the sudoers file...". I can't log as root, and I don't know how to get the password from the AWS administration panel.

Anyone that can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Only the original user created with the instance creation (usually `centos`) can sudo; if you want other users to sudo, you must use that account to set them up.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do precisely and from which client.

Generally in EC2 when you create an instance  it assign a key pair to connect with .

You may retrieve this key pair and log in as ec2-user or whatever the superuser is (refer to your AMI but it should be `centos` user for the instance).

From that session You will be able to  `sudo su -` and add your client user to the /etc/sudoers.

Comment: Ive got a key but i can only login with a user that is not root. Is there a way to get a new key for the root user? If i try to log as root or centos, it asks me for a password that i dont have.

Comment: login as user `centos`.  use `sudo` to get root access.  is this much working for you?   set up other users.  add other users to `/etc/sudoers` and/or set up `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` with your public key (be sure all applicable config files allow root to login).  i suggest that this is a good time to change your ssh port number (and add it to your security group).

Comment: I cant login as centos. When i log in as centos it asks me for a password that i dont have